# how to pass data from view to controller using AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Passing parameter from view to controller using Ajax but, on action, Parameter shows as empty

I have tried passing data by getting the value in a variable first and passing the variable as parameter

Ajax Request

```
$.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Product/Edit',
            data: { Id: $(this).attr('dataid') }, //Id is fetching data but not getting passed to controller
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int  Id)
{
    var Category = ServProd.GetProductForId(Id);
    return PartialView(Category);
}
```

Button:

```
<button class="ProdEdit" type="button" dataid="@Prod.Id">Edit</button>
```

Comment: can you post your view?

Comment: because you're sending a complex object to your controller and not an int, make a model class with `Id` property and it will automatically bind

Comment: i am passing ID as : -- var EditId =  $(this).attr('dataid') and passing ' EditId' to data ,,  dataid="@Prod.Id"  has Id of the product

Answer (score 0):

1) Modify your AJAX call to look like this:

```
const dataToSend = { Id: $(this).attr('dataid') };
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Product/Edit',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) { 
        console.log(`Request passed!`);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(`Request failed!`);
    }
});
```

2) Make a C# model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

3) Change your action method to look like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel RequestModel)
{
    var Category = ServProd.GetProductForId(RequestModel.Id);
    return PartialView(Category);
}
```

Now appropriate [model binding](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/model-binding-in-asp.net-mvc) will take place and you will get your `Id` into the  `RequestModel.Id` property.